# Devise: Redirect to sign up page instead of sign in if no user exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

If no user present, I want a request to be redirected to Sign Up page instead of Login page. So for that, I am overriding the `authenticate_user!` the method in Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  protected

  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path unless User.any?
  end
end
```

Here, the issue is the page isn't redirected properly. The request is getting redirected to the sign-up page but **indefinitely**, i.e. request is not getting completed. On the rails server console it is showing:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Is it a case that there exists `User` record? Where are you redirected to?

Comment: redirection is happening to the sign_up page, but infinitely.

Comment: It's worth including this information in your question, it's kinda important.

Comment: Can you show the result of 'rails routes'?

Answer (score 3):

Devise does *not* recommend overriding the `authenticate_user` and `authenticate_user!` methods.

Instead, define a custom failure app with a route method that returns a symbol representing the named route to redirect to:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

Then inside the Devise initializer, specify your failure app:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp
end
```

If you’re getting an uninitialized constant CustomFailure error, and you’ve put the CustomFailure class under your /lib directory, make sure to autoload your lib files in your application.rb file, like below

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated

Answer (score 0):

Work as well for me, I have fixed for me and my existing projects.

On the `application_controller.rb` run for every request and after overwriting `authenticate_user!` and after callback `before_action :authenticate_user!` all over the controller calling this method also from `SessionsController` and `RegistrationsController` when not `signed_in`, if you use that on separate `controller` then everything is ok like if you use this for `home_controller.rb` then when requesting for `home_controller.rb` without `sign_in` then he will refer to `sign_up` page.

After many searching, I have fixed that like below.

On the `application.rb` I have blocked I mean skipped `before_filter` devise controllers which is work for `login`, `logout` and `signup` like this

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  Devise::RegistrationsController.skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

and the `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

protected
def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'Your custom message here' unless user_signed_in?
end
```

That's it!

***Note***

> After this everything works properly but `devise` default `edit` and `updates` not work.

For this, you have to apply solution 2

**Solution 2**

`devise` default `edit` and `updates` will work if you remove this `!` from `authenticate_user`

like below on the `application.rb`

```
config.to_prepare do
  Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_action :authenticate_user
  Devise::RegistrationsController.skip_before_action :authenticate_user
end
```

and the `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authenticate_user

protected
def authenticate_user
    redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'Your custom message here' unless user_signed_in?
end
```

If you apply this, make sure restart the server after edit `application.rb` file

Hope it helps